# JMeter - JSON response manipulation is not working in JSR223 processor with java

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

```
import net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;

JSONParser p = new JSONParser(JSONParser.MODE_PERMISSIVE);

String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
JSONObject jsonresponse = (JSONObject) p.parse(response);
JSONObject json2 = (JSONObject) jsonresponse.get("Key1");

JSONObject newjson = new JSONObject();
newjson.put("displayValue", json2.get("displayValue"));
newjson.put("value", json2.get("value"));

jsonresponse.put("Key2", newjson);

if(jsonresponse.has("Key3"))
{
    jsonresponse.remove("Key3");
    jsonresponse.put("Key3", jsonresponse.get("Key3").get("value");     
}

log.info(jsonresponse.toString());
```

I need to enter the if loop to remove the json key value if it exists and replace it with something else.

Comment: Getting the below error:

Comment: JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser; import net.minidev.json.JSONObject; i . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Undefined argument: Key3  : at Line: 17 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser; import net.minidev.json.JSONObject; i . . . '' : ( Key3 ) 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser; import net.minidev.json.JSONObject; i . . . '' at line number 17

Comment: Key1 & Key3 are part of the json response

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all of the relevant information in the body of the question, not as comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I believe you need to change at least `if(jsonresponse.has("Key3"))` line to `if(jsonresponse.containsKey("Key3"))`
2. According to JMeter Best Practices [you should not be using Beanshell for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider switching to Groovy language, Groovy performs much better and moreover it has [built-in JSON parsing/generating capabilities](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html). See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for comprehensive explanation, benchmarks, sample code snippets, etc.